# How is Foreign Function Interface (FFI) used with Stack?

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, haskell-stack

I was following some FFI tutorials and examples ([here](https://wiki.haskell.org/FFI_complete_examples) and [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/FFI_Introduction)), and I was wondering what should change when using stack?

In the examples, the source C file is compiled to an object file using `gcc -c -o termops.o termops.c` and included in the gcc compilation using `ghc --make -main-is FfiEx -o ffi_ex FfiEx.hs termops.o`. How can the equivalent be accomplished using stack?

Comment: Stack is not the right component for this - Cabal is. Stack is a tool that helps figure out how to resolve your dependencies, while Cabal describes how to build your project.

Comment: I never really used cabal directly. I went directly to using stack. Can't stack do everything cabal can?

Comment: Not quite. Stack is meant to complement Cabal, not replace it. Internally, Stack relies a fair bit on Cabal.

Comment: So their's no way to run `stack build` and have it compile with a FFI?

Comment: I didn't say that. But the work to get Stack to build an FFI project occurs in the `.cabal` file, not the `.stack` one. I've posted a sample project.

Answer (score 8):

Here is as minimal an FFI C project as I could imagine.

```
$ cd c-proj
c-proj$ ls
Main.hs      c-proj.cabal c_file.c
```

The contents of these files:

- `c-proj.cabal`: describes the

  ```
  name:            c-proj
  version:         0.1.0.0
  cabal-version:   >= 1.22
  build-type:      Simple

  executable main
    main-is:       Main.hs
    build-depends: base >= 4.9
    c-sources:     c_file.c
  ```
- `Main.hs`: the only Haskell source file

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

  module Main where

  foreign import ccall "plus_ten" plusTen :: Int -> IO Int

  main = do
    n <- plusTen 2
    print n
  ```
- `c_file.c`: the C source file

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>

  int plus_ten(int n) {
    printf("%d + 10\n", n);
    return n + 10;
  }
  ```

Then, if you want to use Stack, you can run `stack init`.

```
$ stack init
<< Shell output snipped >>
$ stack build
<< Shell output snipped >>
$ stack exec main
2 + 10
12
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I was looking for. In particular the c-sources section seems to be what I was missing. Follow-up, is there a way to use an object code file instead of the c source file? (File.o instead of File.c)

Comment: Yep, of course! Under the `executable main`, add the following entries: `extra-lib-dirs:  "."` and `extra-libraries: File.o`.

Comment: Just nitpicking: You can do it even more minimal. Just add "build-type: Simple" to the start of c-proj.cabal and get rid of Setup.hs.

Comment: @Krom Hardly a nitpick! That's so handy. I can't believe I've been polluting my projects with (almost always) pointless `Setup.hs` files!